# Create regression coefficient table

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, regression

I have a total of 46 regression models for which I wish to summarize in a data table.  Here's a dummy example I created to help explain my methodology.

```
#Dummy data
Data1 <- data.frame(flow = c(8,8.5,6,7.1,9), SP_elev = c(20,11,5,25,50))
Data2 <- data.frame(flow = c(7,7.2,6.5,8.2,8.5), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data3 <- data.frame(flow = c(2,3,5,7,9), SP_elev = c(20,25,28,30,35))
Data4 <- data.frame(flow = c(1,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data5 <- data.frame(flow = c(1,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(13,15,18,25,19))
Data6 <- data.frame(flow = c(1,4,6,8,9), SP_elev = c(22,23,25,27,29))

#Create blank data frame with desired column names  
tmp <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=0, ncol=9))
names(tmp) <- c("site_name","int", "coflin", "cofsqd", "fstat", "ldf", "udf", "cod", "pval")

#Create Vector list 
dataframes = list("Data1" = Data1, 
                  "Data2" = Data2, 
                  "Data3" = Data3,
                  "Data4" = Data4,
                  "Data5" = Data5,
                  "Data6" = Data6) 

#plot a with regression model
for (i in dataframes) {

#Create regression model
fit2<-lm(SP_elev ~ flow + I(flow^2), data=i) 
pol2 <- function(x) fit2$coefficient[3]*x^2 + fit2$coefficient[2]*x + fit2$coefficient[1] 

#Create variables for each coefficient
site_name <- i
int <- signif(summary(fit2)$coefficients[1],4)
coflin <- signif(summary(fit2)$coefficients[2],4)
cofsqd <- signif(summary(fit2)$coefficients[3],4)
fstat <- signif(summary(fit2)$fstatistic,4)
ldf <- signif(summary(fit2)$fstatistic[2],2)
udf <- signif(summary(fit2)$fstatistic[3],2)
cod <- signif(summary(fit2)$adj.r.squared,3)
pval <- signif(pf(fstat,ldf,udf,lower.tail=FALSE),4

#add variables to the dataframe 'tmp'

}
```

My methodology is currently:

1. input dummy data
2. create blank data frame
3. create vector list of the dummy data
4. run for loop to perform the regression analysis on each data set.

   a. format the respective variables for addition to the data frame `tmp`

   b. append the formatted variables to the data frame `tmp` row by row (i
   row per dummy data set)

As can be seen above, I do not quite know how to add the variables to the data frame `tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your loop to be a counter instead of actual data frame objects, this becomes pretty straightforward:

```
tmp <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=length(dataframes), ncol=9))
names(tmp) <- c("site_name","int", "coflin", "cofsqd", "fstat", "ldf", "udf", "cod", "pval")
for(j in seq_along(dataframes)) {
  i <- dataframes[[j]]

  # rest of your code goes here

  new.row <- c(names(dataframes)[[j]], int, coflin, ..., cod, pval)
  tmp[j, ] <- new.row
}
```

Notice how you can't use `i` as the id as that is a data frame, but you can use the corresponding name.  Also, we initialized the results data frame to be the correct size in number of rows.

One thing to watch out for is that modifying data frames is slow, so you typically don't want to do this in a loop unless your loop doesn't iterate that many times.  If it does, one simple solution is use a matrix first, and convert it to data frame after you are done looping.

Comment: I am currency investigating the matrix method.